# Returning a Future from an akka Mapper

Tags: java, akka, future

My problem is best described by the following (simplified) example:

Given an asynchronous HTTP client which returns `Future< JSON >` on calls to its get-Method.
Given a link to a resource which in turn contains a link to another resource. How then do I code the following:

- perform GET for Resource A
- as soon as that GET has finished, perform GET for Resource B

My specific problem is, how to return a Future from within the Mapper, without resourceB having to be of type `Future< Future < JSON > >`. Basically, what I'd like to write is the following:

```
Future< JSON > resourceA = httpClient.get( "http://..." );
Future< JSON > resourceB = resourceA.map( new Mapper< JSON, Future< JSON > >() {
     public JSON apply( JSON resourceARepr )
     {
        return httpClient.get( resourceARepr.getString( "linkToResourceB" ) );
     }
} );
```

However, that does not compile, because `httpClient#get` returns a `Future`, while the `Future#map` method expects me to pass a mapper which maps from the supplied value  synchronously.

From `Promises/A` in the JavaScript world I am used to promise handlers being able to return a promise to a value or a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer to my problem is as simple as using flatMap instead of map. Oops.